# Geoserver shutdown after load big imagemosaic

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic

catalina.log:
24.05.2013 15:33:38 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint processSocket
SEVERE: Error allocating socket processor
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
        at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:657)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.start(JIoEndpoint.java:513)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.newWorkerThread(JIoEndpoint.java:744)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.createWorkerThread(JIoEndpoint.java:723)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.getWorkerThread(JIoEndpoint.java:757)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.processSocket(JIoEndpoint.java:789)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:355)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

......................

and

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.font.FontManager
        at sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment$2.run(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:179)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:163)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:253)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor109.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
        at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.createGraphics(BufferedImage.java:1152)
        at javax.media.jai.TiledImageGraphics.getBogusGraphics2D(TiledImageGraphics.java:266)
        at javax.media.jai.TiledImageGraphics.(TiledImageGraphics.java:192)
        at javax.media.jai.TiledImage.createGraphics(TiledImage.java:755)
        at javax.media.jai.ROIShape.getAsImage(ROIShape.java:1148)
        at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.MosaicOpImage.(MosaicOpImage.java:374)
        at com.sun.media.jai.mlib.MlibMosaicOpImage.(MlibMosaicOpImage.java:49)
        at com.sun.media.jai.mlib.MlibMosaicRIF.create(MlibMosaicRIF.java:74)

...................

and more

ERROR [geotools.map] - Call MapContent dispose() to prevent memory leaks

..............

After run layer preview(big imagemosaic) geoserver(and other opengeo) send error 502.

Answer (score 1):

You've run out of memory - add more memory to the JVM that is running your container. Exactly how you do that depends to an extent on which you are using but it will be something like

export JAVA_OPTS = $JAVA_OPTS -Xmx256M -Xms48m

See http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/container.html for a fuller list of possibilities

Comment: in /etc/default/tomcat6 now JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms48m -Xmx256m -Xrs -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.geotools.referencing.forceXY=true"

Comment: after restart: Exception in thread "Thread-11" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.h2.util.RandomUtils$1.run(RandomUtils.java:58)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

Comment: and not show big imagemosaic.